# How to use function argument in `@sprintf` in Julia?

Tags: string, macros, format, julia

The following errors:

```
function num_to_string(x,format="%.1f")
    @sprintf format x
end
```

The error is:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Printf.Format(::Symbol)
```

I tried using the `@sprintf(format,x)` form, as well as interpolating(?) like `@sprintf $format x`

How can I use variables in the `@sprintf` format?

Comment: Macros work at parse-time. At parse-time, the text `format x` becomes the `Symbol`s `:format` and `:x`. The variable `format` and its value`"%.1f"` doesn't exist until compile-time, long after parse-time is done and macros did their work. You need a *function* that works on variables and values at run-time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@sprintf` is a macro, and converts the format string into a processed `Format` object during macro-expansion itself. This is good for performance, but means that `@sprintf` is limited to literal strings as formats, not variables.

However, you can directly make the function call that `@sprintf` [ultimately makes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/stdlib/Printf/src/Printf.jl#L914), and since that would be an ordinary function call (and not a macro invocation), you can use a variable as the format argument:

```
julia> function num_to_string(x,fmt="%.1f")
           Printf.format(Printf.Format(fmt), x)
       end
num_to_string (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> num_to_string(45)
"45.0"

julia> num_to_string(pi, "%.5f")
"3.14159"
```